# js как добавить короткую функцию addEventListener

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
function get(s){
    return document.querySelector(s);
}

function getAll(s){
    return document.querySelectorAll(s);
}
Node.prototype.click=function(ev){
    this.addEventListener("click",ev)
}

NodeList.prototype.click=function(ev){
    this.forEach(el=>el.addEventListener("click",ev))
}

window.onload=function(){
    get("b").click(function(){
        console.log(this)
    })

    getAll("b").click(function(){
        console.log(this)
    })
}

<b>1</b>
<b>2</b>
<b>3</b>
<b>4</b>
<b>5</b>
```

NodeList работает а Node почему то нет. в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в количестве уровней имплементации:

[`.querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) возвращает конкретный [Element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element)

Цепочка прототипов полученного элемента выглядит так:

```
HtmlElement
Element
Node
```

При этом, непосредственно свойство `click` есть сразу у `HtmlElement`.

Таким образом, поиск до `Node.prototype.click` просто не доходит.

Comment: и как же повесить .click() на Node?

Comment: @axmed2004, нужно удалить click непосредственно у элемента :)

Answer (score 0):

В том, что у элемента уже есть функция `click`.

```js
function get(s) {
  return document.querySelector(s);
}

function getAll(s) {
  return document.querySelectorAll(s);
}
Node.prototype.click1 = function(ev) {
  this.addEventListener("click", ev)
}

NodeList.prototype.click = function(ev) {
  this.forEach(el => el.addEventListener("click", ev))
}

window.onload = function() {
  console.log(get("b").click);
  
  get("b").click1(function() {
    console.log(this)
  })

  getAll("b").click(function() {
    console.log(this)
  })
}
```

```html
<b>1</b>
<b>2</b>
<b>3</b>
<b>4</b>
<b>5</b>
```

Comment: у Node есть функция `onclick`, а я хочу чтобы работала как prototype.click

Comment: @axmed2004, так не получится

Comment: @axmed2004 We don't always get what we want.